# Do fast moving objects appear blurred?

Tags: special-relativity

I am considering the view of object moving at near light velocity
It is described in

https://physicsworld.com/a/the-invisibility-of-length%E2%80%AFcontraction/

I have some comments mainly to the first picture
about the Lorentz contraction disappearing for a cube moving at near the speed of light.
The issue has to do with special relativity but I am providing a classical thought experiment.

Let us assume a cube is travelling from left to right in a path at some distance to an observer, who places a slit that allows for a line of sight perpendicular to the cube's path at a point X. The cube is positioned so that it with a front side perpendicular to the path and the observer cannot see the cube's upper and lower side.

We consider the situation where the cube's front face has reached the point X at a time T.

The width of the slit allows for a view of a small part of the cube, neglectible in relation to the length of the cube.

The observer can therefore see the edge of the leading front side through the slit.

A new slit is the placed slightly to the left of the first slit allowing the observer to see - from the same observation point and if the cube were at rest - a segment of the side of the cube facing the observer, at some distance from the front edge, at a point X-dx.

We now assume that the cube's speed is high so that the difference in time of flight through the two slits matters.

We can arrange the geometry and cube speed so that the time of flight difference, dt, between the paths through the two slits, matches the time it takes the cube to travel the distance dx.

We would then see one of the cube's leading edges through both slits. In addition, photons from the front side of the cube leaving even before the time T-dt would leave the cube together with photons from the cube's side and arrive simultaneously through the second slit.

Based on this very simple and classical mechanic picture, I wonder: will any view of fast moving objects not be considerably - or completely -  blurred?

Comment: See generally the topic of Terrell rotations.  Also [this site](https://www.spacetimetravel.org/) has some nice animations for downloads, like [this one](https://www.spacetimetravel.org/tuebingen).

Comment: [Animations of the visual appearance of fast-moving objects](https://www.spacetimetravel.org/ueberblick/1).

Comment: Objects are _not_ rotated, you see the back of them because they are _behind_ you!  Look up relativistic aberration, and ignore that over-complicated and misleading article.

Comment: I appreciate you comments. However I also note that, as opposed to viewing a stationary object, there are several directions in which we see the same point of a viewed object in motion, for both newtonian and relativistic mechanics.